# Does it mean we get inspired by people in a wrong or overwhelmed way so that we get baffled

Tags: sentence-meaning

People are inspiring. The lengths many of us go to for others is baffling.

Comment: Can you provide context or a source for where this quote came from?

Comment: https://medium.com/personal-growth/everything-i-have-learned-in-500-words-6c4a5ccbc8e1

Comment: The "baffling" part means that what we are willing to do for other people is far above what you might expect.

Answer (score 2):

In your example

> The lengths many of us go to for others is **baffling**.

"*baffling*" describes the "*lengths*" or "*effort*" that people will go to to help other people.

"*Baffling*" in this case means "*unexplainable*" or "*not understandable*" since the efforts may seem to be very great, far outweighing the results.